# Difference between 'highland' and 'upland'

Tags: differences

The Cambridge Dictionary provides the following definitions of these two terms:

[Highland](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/highlands):

> a mountainous area of a country.

[Uplands](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uplands)

> high areas of land.

The definitions mentioned above are almost alike; the high areas denotes the mountainous areas, while the mountainous areas denotes a high area. But, how to use them accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Highlands** would typically refer to areas that are mountainous with undulating terrain of peaks and valleys, such as the Scottish Highlands.

**Uplands** would refer to areas that are at a height above sea level, but are not necessarily mountainous. These would be plateaus or plains.

An example of such would be the interior of South Africa which is at a height above sea level, but is largely flat. This region is referred to locally as highveld.

Answer (score 1):

Both Highlands and Uplands are plateaus, but the difference between them is:

> The Highland is a plateau that is high, especially because of Mountains.
>   While the Upland is also a plateau, but not necessarily mountainous.